# enviar email usando php

Tags: php, phpmailer, sendmail

Gente o meu programa esta dando um único erro de sintaxe na penúltima linha e eu não entendo o porquê. Alguém me ajuda pf.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"pt_BR");
    require_once 'PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php';
    require_once 'PHPMailer/class.smtp.php';

    function sendMail($para,$de,$mensagem,$assunto)
    {
        //dados tmp
        $smtp= "smtp.gmail.com";

        $usuario="symphlower@gmail.com";
        $senha = "xxxxxxxxxxx";


        $mail = new smtp;
        $mail->Delivery('relay');

        $mail->Relay($smtp,$usuario,$senha,465,'login',true);

        $mail->TimeOut(10);
        $mail->Priority('high');

        $mail->From($de);
        $mail->AddTo($para);
        $mail->Html($mensagem);

            if($mail->Send($assunto))
            {
                echo "alert('Deu certo')";
                $_SESSION['feedback']="Mensagem enviada com sucesso";
                header ("Location: feedback_index.html");
            }
            else
            {
                echo "alert('Deu errado')";
                $_SESSION['feedback'] ="Mensagem não foi enviada";
                header("Location: feedback_index.html");
            }
    }

    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $assunto = $_POST['assunto'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];

    $corpo = 
        '<html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>

        Nome:<br>'.$nome.'<p>
        Email:<br>'.$email.'<p>
        Assunto:<br>'.$assunto.'<p>
        Menssagem:<br>'.$mensagem.'<p>      

        </body>
        </html>';

    sendMail('symphlower@gmail.com',$email,$corpo,$assunto); //está dando erro aqui
?>
```

Comment: E qual é exatamente a mensagem de erro?

Comment: está faltando .com no seu e-mail!

Comment: @JonathandeToni eu coloquei ".com" e o erro continuou

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss ele da erro de sintaxe "ERROR 500".

Comment: Tenta utilizar a porta 587. Muito utilizado o gmail, hotmail e afins...

Comment: @JonathandeToni ainda nada de funcionar kkk vou tentar fazer de novo.

Comment: Ok, assim que refazer e se gerar um erro diferente, ou correção edita a sua pergunta com a solução.

Comment: No log de erro do servidor deve aparecer uma mensagem mais detalhada do erro.

Comment: Você está testando `localmente` ou no seu servidor?

Comment: $mail = new smtp;   Não seria new PHPMailer()

Comment: Adicione a mensagem de erro à pergunta para que seja claro para todos.

Comment: @RafaelAugusto to usando no servidor

Comment: @LeoNogueira mas eu to usando SMTP, por que colocaria PHPMailer()?